# Exclude files from list in for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have difficulties to assign filtered list into variable that would be used in for loop, TEST_SCRIPTS (just all files in catalog) is working well, but when I'm trying to use filtered list, which works when I just display the catalog using @dir, but trying to assign it to TEST_SCRIPTS_2 it's not working in the loop.

```
@echo off 

SET TEST_SCRIPTS=cat_1\*.sql

echo filtered files list:
@dir %TEST_SCRIPTS% /b | findstr /b /e /v /i /l /g:exclude.txt

SET TEST_SCRIPTS_2 = @dir %TEST_SCRIPTS% /b | findstr /b /e /v /i /l /g:exclude.txt
REM                  /\ tried without @dir too

echo working loop:
for /r %%i in (%TEST_SCRIPTS%) do (
    echo %%i
    
REM "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\psql.exe" -h localhost -p %DB_PORT% -d %DB_NAME% -U %DB_USER% -w -af %%i 
)

echo not working loop:
for /r %%i in (%TEST_SCRIPTS_2%) do (
    echo %%i
)
```

Comment: 1. You don't have a variable `%TEST_SCRIPTS_2%`. You have a `%TEST_SCRIPTS_2 %` though. Remove the spaces around `=` with the `set` command.

Comment: 2. You need single quotes with the `for` loop to let it execute a command. See `for /?` for details.

Comment: I removed a space but it's still the same, echo in the first loop is executed okay, it prints path to all the files in cat_1, but the second loop doesn't print anything. Turning echo on for this command shows
 for /R %i in ((null)) do

Comment: I see however a difference, that @dir prints only filenames, where first, working loop prints whole path. But I can't figure it out what else I can try

Comment: You do realize your `exclude.txt` would need to have on each line, the fully qualified absolute path of each file.

Comment: But @dir %TEST_SCRIPTS% /b | findstr /b /e /v /i /l /g:exclude.txt
is able to bring me filtered list of filenames, so couldn't it be used somehow in loop?

Comment: If you're doing this recursively, you could change your file list to use just the filename, so you can match strings ending with ```\basename.ext```.